# loading data in fragment using http request

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `Fragment` and I want to load some JSON data into it by making an HTTP request.

What's the right practice to make a request in `Activity` and pass the data to the `Fragment` or Load the data in the `Fragment` directly?

Currently, I am loading the data in the `Fragment` directly but I have keep checking fragment `isAdded()` and `getActivity()` is not `null` after data is loaded and when going to display it inside fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the loading of data belongs to the fragment. Otherwise, if your MainActivity has 5 fragments, your code will be complex and confusing.

You could also define a class that is responsible for loading the data. Something like that (pseudocode!):

```
public class FragmentCustomerList extends Fragment implements OnCustomersLoadedCallback {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        showLoadingDataView(); // show data loading spinner

        DataLoader.instance().loadCustomersASYNC(this);
    }

    // OnCustomersLoadedCallback 

    @Overrride
    public void onDataLoaded(List<Customer> customers){

        hideLoadingDataView(); // hide data loading spinner

        showData(customers);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah thats what I thought and loading data in fragment but problem is after completion of background process I have to keep checking getActivity() is null or not and fragment isAdded or not.

Comment: I updated my answer.  you should start loading your data after the fragment was added. Doit inside of `onStart()` or `onResume()` method.

Comment: yeah event I am doing same but when you display loaded data will have to check fragment is added or not or activity is there or not. Because it might happen data is loaded and user presses back button now activity doesnt exist and you might face a crash

Comment: sure. check it before you update the view. If you load date in your MainActivity you will probably have to check if your fragment visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't effect the fragment or activity at all, as the request done in background. It depends on your condition that whether you want to display the content just after the fragment appearance or you can wait inside the fragment. For example :- if you don't want to display the fragment's views so just perform request operation and wait inside the activity, as you get the results just move back to the fragment. Hope this will help you